# Find key value in list of dictionaries, and then replace the other values

Tags: python, json, list, loops, dictionary

I'm using Python and a JSON file containing a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[
  {'name':'person1','id':'123','status':'absent'},
  {'name':'person2','id':'0980','status':'away'},
  {'name':'person3','id':'5235','status':'present'}
]
```

And I have an incoming dictionary with the same format:

```
{'name':'person1','id':'324','status':'present'}
```

The incoming dictionary can have one thing in common, and that's the `name` key, if the value for the 'name' key hasn't been seen, I add it the `json` file, if it has, I update the values for the `id` and `status` keys in the `json` file. I'm having trouble updating the list of dictionaries in the `json` file.

Taking the examples I gave above, the resulting `json` file should look like this:

```
[
  {'name':'person1','id':'324','status':'present'},
  {'name':'person2','id':'0980','status':'away'},
  {'name':'person3','id':'5235','status':'present'}
]
```

I can manage to find the dictionary I want to change with the following:

```
dict_to_update = next(item for item in <jsonfilename> if item['name'] == 'desired name')
```

After this, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to then update the specific dictionary in the `json` file.
Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how:

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as r:
    lst = json.load(r)

for i,d in enumerate(lst):
    if d['name'] == dct['name']:
        lst[i] = dct

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(lst , f)
```

---

---

You can also use a function:

```
def update(lst):
    for i,d in enumerate(lst):
        if d['name'] == dct['name']:
            lst[i] = dct
    return lst

with open('file.json', 'r') as r:
    lst = update(json.load(r))

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(lst , f)
```

Comment: I imagine the l[i] is supposed to be lst[i]?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_dict = [
    {"name": "person1", "id": "123", "status": "absent"},
    {"name": "person2", "id": "0980", "status": "away"},
    {"name": "person3", "id": "5235", "status": "present"},
]

incoming_dictionary = {"name": "person1", "id": "324", "status": "present"}

for index, dictionary in enumerate(list_of_dict):
    if incoming_dictionary["name"] == dictionary["name"]:
        list_of_dict[
            index
        ] = incoming_dictionary  # replace the dictionary with the new one
        break
else:
    # if no match was found then append the incoming dictionary
    list_of_dict.append(incoming_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does so, maybe not as elegantly as other answers:

```
def process(new_dict):
    global data  #jsonfilename
    if new_dict['name'] in [d['name'] for d in data]:
        data = [d for d in data if d['name'] != new_dict['name']]
    data.append(new_dict)
    data = sorted(data, key=lambda i: i['name'])
```

Full example:

```
data = [{'name':'person1','id':'123','status':'absent'},
        {'name':'person2','id':'0980','status':'away'},
        {'name':'person3','id':'5235','status':'present'}]

process({'name':'person1','id':'324','status':'present'})  #an overwritten person
process({'name':'person4','id':'324','status':'present'})  #a new person
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'person1', 'id': '324', 'status': 'present'},
 {'name': 'person2', 'id': '0980', 'status': 'away'},
 {'name': 'person3', 'id': '5235', 'status': 'present'},
 {'name': 'person4', 'id': '324', 'status': 'present'}]
```

You can do this while avoiding the `global` keyword as well, but I thought this seemed alright for modifying an existing structure in place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, and if you found another short solution please let me know.
I make an iteration for the list of dictionary, and add a conditional to change the value of key id and status.
Another way is we can use filter and map, to have a short code instead.

```
datas = [{'name': 'person1', 'id': '123', 'status': 'absent'}, {'name': 'person2', 'id': '0980',
                                                    'status': 'away'}, {'name': 'person3', 'id': '5235', 'status': 'present'}]
newData = {'name':'person1','id':'324','status':'present'}
for data in datas:
    if data["name"]==newData["name"]:
        data["id"]=newData["id"]
        data["status"]=newData["status"]
```